# I am unable to open the store on my Lumia 525 to download apps

Tags: 8.1, store

When I am trying to open the store to download an app on my Nokia Lumia 525 it is showing the error code - `805a8011`, even after rebooting I am unable to open the store, what should I do now?
Please let me know the process on how I can open the store to download apps; I even  tried to go to settings and get an update but it is not opening since the result is the same.

Comment: Is the date, time and timezone correct on your phone?

Answer (score 4):

The error code 805a8011 occurs due to the following reasons

- Microsoft account sync problem
- Lack of sufficient space in your Windows phone
- Incorrect date and time set in your phone
- Problem with your Microsoft Live Account
- Internet problem

**Fixing the error**

There are six solutions to fix this error. They are

**Solution 1**: Set correct date and time

Go to *Settings->Time and Date* and set the correct date and time.

**Solution 2** : Free up memory on phone

You can do this moving your photos, files and apps to SD card.

**Solution 3** : Manually Synchronize your Microsoft Account

1. Open Settings option.
2. Click on Email + Account.
3. Tap and hold on your Microsoft Account.
4. Now, tap on Synchronize

**Solution 4** : Add New Microsoft Live Account

Sometimes, you may face Error Code 805a8011 in Windows Phone even if you have entered correct username and password. It is because you may be using a semi-functional Microsoft Account. So, to fix it add new Microsoft Live Account in your Windows Phone

**Solution 5** : Switch your internet connection

As mentioned above that sometimes this error can arise due to internet problem. So, switch your internet connection. If you are using WiFi connection, then switch to data connection or vice-versa.

**Solution 6** : Reset your phone

Go to *Settings->About->Reset your Phone*.

Here, you will be prompted to two warning message. Just tap on Yes and move further.

External links : [Techbae.com](http://www.techbae.com/fix-error-code-805a8011-in-windows-phone/)